# Getting a list of changed files in BitBucket Pipelines

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I know that I can limit specific steps to "condition: changesets: includePaths:" That's not what I'm trying to do.

I know that I can get a list of modified files **in the last commit** with `git diff`. That, unfortunately, isn't sufficient.

What I would like to do is get a list of all of the files which have been modified in this branch **since last push**. For instance, imagine that you do the following:

1. Create a branch.
2. Commit A.
3. Push.
4. Commit B.
5. Commit C.
6. Commit D.
7. Push.

I want a list of the files modified in all of B, C and D so that I can pass them to my testing scripts and evaluate all of the files which have been modified since the last time the pipeline was able to run.

With **pull-requests**, I think I can do this by diffing `BITBUCKET_COMMIT` and `BITBUCKET_PR_DESTINATION_BRANCH`. But for pipeline steps which I want to run simply any time commits are pushed, I can't figure out how to get the changeset I want.

Answer (score 0):

For someone looking for answer to this question in 2023 or thereafter, one way we could get the list of updated objects in a pull request in a pipeline build using Bitbucket API, for example:

```
# Get the PR diffstat URL
curl --request GET --url "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/pullrequests/{pull_request_id}" --header "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>" --header "Accept: application/json" -o response.json

DIFFSTAT_URL=$(jq -r .links.diffstat.href response.json)

curl --request GET --url "${DIFFSTAT_URL}" --header "Authorization:Bearer <access_token>" --header "Accept: application/json" -o diffstat.json

jq -r .values[].new.path diffstat.json > changelog.txt
```

Source: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pullrequests